# gcc compiler with opengl linker issue (cmd)

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, cmd, g++

There are header files which i included in .cpp file, but it cannot link the gl file.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
> #include <GLUT/glut.h>
> #else
> #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
> #include <windows.h>
> #endif
> #include <GL/glut.h>
> #include <GL/glu.h>
> #include<GL/gl.h>
> #endif
```

[image: The issue is when i compile code trhough cmd it shows an error which is given below.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` switch of the gcc compiler specifies the library file that you want to link during the linking phase of the compiler.

It seems you that the command you are executing to compile & link the code is referencing the library file `-lgl` (i.e., gl.lib), which doesn't exists in your default Library search path (LIBRARY_PATH).

Having said that, there is no such gl.lib file provided by the Windows SDK or GLFW. Instead, what you would want to do is to include the opengl32.lib library which is required by the opengl API in your gcc command as follows:

`gcc main.cpp -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglfw3`